# Supply provided dependencies with build flag in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project that's main purpose is to provide a collection of algorithms to client.  However, it secondarily handles a HTTP interfaces to those algorithms.  Since I don't want my clients to inherent the HTTP libraries (`unfiltered` and `dispatch`) I have them scoped as `provided` in sbt.  How can I set up my project so that when I `sbt assembly`, these dependencies (along with a logging implementation) are compiled but when I `sbt package` or `sbt publish` they are not?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is as simple as telling the assembly plugin to use the *compile* configuration of jars instead of the runtime dependency (since provided are not on the runtime classpath).

sbt 0.13 syntax:

```
fullClasspath in assembly := (fullClasspath in Compile).value
```